# Using keyword and Managed\UnManaged code

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, using-statement, managed-code

> C# keyword Using implements Idisposable which provides a mechanism for
>   releasing unmanaged resources.

Now i was going through this code

```
string txt = String.Empty;
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename)) {
         txt = sr.ReadToEnd();
      }
```

and cant stop wondering, why is the keyword **Using** is used in this code while **StreamReader** is a Managed resource and it is the responsibility of the garbage collector to free up the objects memory after its scope gets over.

So my question is,

1. Is the above code simply an explicit way of handling to free up resources
2. As per my understanding any methods or classes which we use under the .net framework is a managed code, then is not StreamReader also falls under managed code.
3. Am i missing something on the Managed\Unmanaged code

Comment: the ``StreamReader`` possibly be using in it's implementation some unmanaged resources, so it will make sure they are disposed when wrapped inside using

Comment: .. so in the example you provided, this would be the file handle used to open the file for reading.

Comment: File I/O is an operating system specific service, In Windows a handle approach is used, handles need closing.

Comment: Surely whatever source you're quoting from provided more information than just that one sentence (if it did not, you could no doubt have looked for others).  There's no shortage of information on this topic out there.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Sajjad will not disposing the StreamReader object clears up the memory and so the unmanaged code also gets cleared? can you give me a little more details on the working

Comment: See the `StreamReader.Dispose(Boolean)` Description: Closes the underlying stream, releases the unmanaged resources used by the StreamReader, and optionally releases the managed resources.(Overrides TextReader.Dispose(Boolean).)

Comment: @JamesC.TaylorIV has given the reference, you can look in details of that method on MSDN

Answer (score 1):

> why is the keyword Using is used in this code while StreamReader is a
>   Managed resource

While StreamReader is a managed object it may hold objects inside it which are not allocated on the managed heap. Garbage Collector has no visibility on their allocation and hence cannot clean them up. For the particular case of `StreamReader` it internally creates a `FileStream` (for your particular case) which internally creates and holds a WIN32 filehandle.

```
_handle = Win32Native.SafeCreateFile(tempPath, fAccess, share, secAttrs, mode, flagsAndAttributes, IntPtr.Zero);
```

(Code [Reference](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,76ef6c04de9d0ed8))

`using` is just shorthand for:

```
try
{
   var streamReader = new StreamReader(path);
   // code
} 
finally
{
  streamReader.Dispose();
}
```

Methods implementing `IDisposable` need to implement `Dispose` where they get the opportunity to close file handles, sockets, or any such resource that may need manual cleaning.

If one choses to hold a `StreamReader` inside a class then that class should implement `IDisposable` too, to correctly pass on the `Dispose` to the `StreamReader`.

So the `IDisposable` can be considered as a contract **for classes that either hold native objects, or hold objects that implement IDisposable**

Answer (score -5):

I think this is more of a defensive coding style where I don't want the stream reader object to be used as the file associated with this object has already been read completely using ReadtoEnd function and is being referred by txt.

Comment: This is untrue.  `using` exists to ensure guaranteed (or at least as close to it as is possible) and prompt cleanup of unmanaged resources.  It is not *just* a scoping mechanism.

Comment: The request to read the file has been fulfilled by an operating system API, this API requires notification when I/O is complete to free associated resources.  If something implements IDisposable, dispose it, always.